# How to pass values to a formula?

Tags: python, string, function, math, integer

How Do I pass values say `12,32,34` to formula `x+y+z` in python without assigning manually?
I have tried using `**args` but the results is `None`.

```
def myFormula(*args):
    lambda x, y: x+y+z(*args)
print(myFormula(1,2,3))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```py
formula = lambda x,y,z: x+y+z
print(formula(1,2,3))
```

there is no need to use *args there.

here is an example of using a function for a formula

```py
# a = (v - u)/t
acceleration = lambda v, u, t: (v - u)/t
print(acceleration(23, 12, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

A regular function doesn't require doing any manual assignments:

```
def myFormula(x,y,z):
    return sum((x,y,z))

print(myFormula(1,2,3))
```

You can handle an arbitrary number of arguments in this situation like this:

```
def myFormula(*args):
    return sum(args)

print(myFormula(1,2,3,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `sum`:

```
print(sum([1, 2, 3]))
```

Output:

```
6
```

If you want a `def` try this:

```
def myFormula(*args):
    return sum(args)
print(myFormula(1, 2, 3))
```

Output:

```
6
```